# Does NSThread setThreadPriority work on simulator (or on hardware)?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios-simulator

On Xcode 4 iPad simulator, when I do NSThread +setThreadPriority, then check threadPriority, the result is always 0.5, regardless of what I set.  (+setThreadPriority returns a YES/"success" return code.)

Is this purely a simulator problem, or does setThreadPriority simply not work?

(I'm trying to find some way to force a "background" thread to yield the CPU -- pthread_yield_np doesn't appear to work, on the simulator, at least.)

**Added:**  Apparently the simulator is pretty brain dead.  Even sleeping 5 seconds in the "background" thread will not allow the main thread to run.  (The main thread is waiting on an `@synchronize` lock and the "background" thread is in the "get lock instance" code, well before it has a chance to actually get the lock.)

(Except that, sigh, the "background" thread may have recursive locks.  I wonder if there's a way to test for that?)

**Added more:** Yep, the problem is not the inability to switch threads on the simulator, but rather the fact that this app has some recursive locks in a long-running background thread, and those locks (early in the stack) are holding off the main thread.  Thought required.

(But it's pretty clear that setThreadPriority ***does not*** work on the simulator.)

Comment: I think that's just a limitation of the simulator. What do you see on an actual device?

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan - Haven't tried it on the device yet -- will steal one tomorrow to give it a shot.

Comment: Do you have some code to share on using `Thread` and `setPriority()` ?  The `GCD` is far insufficient for my purposes and i'm going native. Just is _zero_ documentation for it in `swift`.